# What is the function of particle に in this sentence? みんなお寺に名前を登録しなければなりませんでした。

Tags: particle-に, particle-で

What is the function of the particle に in this sentence?

> みんなお寺**に**名前を登録しなければなりませんでした。

That means that everyone had to register their names in temples? But why isn't there で particle then (place of action function)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but they have different meanings.

お寺**で**名前を登録する means "to register their names **at** the temple". The temple happens to be where they registered their names. Their names will be recorded in the list which may or may not be managed by the temple itself.

お寺**に**名前を登録する means "to register their names **with** the temple". It's clear that your names will be managed by the temple.

Comment: わかりました。どうもありがとうございます。